# Is there a good explanation about how iPhone OS works?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to read more about how the iPhone OS actually works. I know for example there is an application sandbox, and some globally interchanged folgers where all apps have access to, like address book. I'd like to know more about how the components of iPhone OS fit together, what's there, etc. maybe someone has a good link that summarizes all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your looking for: http://thecoffeedesk.com/news/index.php/2009/05/17/iphone-architecture/

Answer (score 1):

There's a wealth of info in the [iPhone developer center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)

Comment: Hear, hear! The Apple documentation is quite readable and quite extensive.